# advanced indexing using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to use advanced indexing but I cannot get it to work with this simple array

```
arr = np.array([[[ 1, 10, 100,1000],[ 2, 20, 200,2000]],[[ 3, 30, 300,3000],[ 4,40,400,4000]],[[5, 50, 500,5000],[6, 60,600,6000]]])

d1=np.array([0])
d2=np.array([0,1])
d3=np.array([0,1,2])  

arr[d1,d2,d3]

IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,) (2,) (3,)
```

and

```
arr[d1[:,np.newaxis],d2[np.newaxis,:],d3]

IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,1) (1,2) (3,)
```

Expected output:

```
array([[[  1,  10, 100],
        [  2,  20, 200]]])
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I updated the question with expected output

Comment: You may be looking for `arr[np.ix_(d1,d2,d3)]`.

Comment: look at the `ix_` output to see how your `newaxis` approach should have worked.  You may need to review `broadcasting` rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.ix_` to combine several one-dimensional index arrays of different lengths to index a multidimensional array. For example:

```
arr[np.ix_(d1,d2,d3)]
```

To add more context, `np.ix_` returns a tuple of ndimensional arrays. The same can be achieved "by hand" by adding `np.newaxis` for appropriate dimensions:

```
xs, ys, zs = np.ix_(d1,d2,d3)

# xs.shape == (1, 1, 1) == (len(d1), 1,       1      )
# ys.shape == (1, 2, 1) == (1,       len(d2), 1      )
# zs.shape == (1, 1, 3) == (1,       1,       len(d3))

result_ix = arr[xs, ys, zs]

# using newaxis:

result_newaxis = arr[
  d1[:,          np.newaxis, np.newaxis],
  d2[np.newaxis, :,          np.newaxis],
  d3[np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :],
]

assert (result_ix == result_newaxis).all()
```

Comment: It might be nice if you showed why `ix_` worked.

Answer (score 1):

You need only `d1` to select the first cell:

```
>>> arr[d1]
array([[[  1,  10, 100],
        [  2,  20, 200]]])
```